# ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement using load data infile

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle

Im having problems with this SQL statement. Im programming in java with eclipse juno ide, and sql developer. My query is:

```
    private static String SQL_QUERY = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\...\\myfile.csv' " +
        "INTO TABLE mytable " +
        "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '" + '"' + "' " +
        "LINES TERMINATED BY " + "'\\n' " +
        "IGNORE 1 LINES";
```

I read sintax from [load data infile syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/load-data.html) from oracle docs. And my code is:

```
public void LoadDataInFile()
{
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstm = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
    try
    {
        conn = connectionFactory.getConnection();
        pstm = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_QUERY);
        resultSet = pstm.executeQuery();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Reading on forums i found than maybe im using the wrong methods, so i tried:

```
private static String SQL_QUERY = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ? INTO TABLE ? " +
            "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ? OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ?" +
            "LINES TERMINATED BY ?" +
            "IGNORE ? LINES";

public void LoadDataInFile()
{
    Connection conn = null;
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
    CallableStatement cstmt = null; 
    try
    {
        conn = connectionFactory.getConnection();
        cstmt = conn.prepareCall(SQL_QUERY);
        cstmt.setString(1, "C:\\...\\myfile.csv");
        cstmt.setString(2, "mytable");
        cstmt.setString(3, "','");
        cstmt.setString(4, "'" + '"'  +"'");
        cstmt.setString(5, "'\\n'");
        cstmt.setInt(6, 1);
        cstmt.executeUpdate();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And still not working.
A few things:

- I used "..." in path to make it easier to read.
- My file is in csv format.
- My file is in local, but db is not.
- the method "conn = connectionFactory.getConnection();" returns an OracleDataSource object.

So, what im doing wrong here?? Im new to this so a good explanation it will be very appreciated. I just need to copy the content from the file to a table, if this is not a good way to do it, or there is a better way, it is welcome too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, `load data infile` is MySQL-specific and there is no Oracle implementation of it.

Comment: You cannot run `SQL*Loader` through `JDBC`.

Comment: Thanks for fast response. The link i put in my question, is from oracle site. But is true that, it is very similar to the MySQL one. Can anyone confirm this? I dont understand why would they document something i cant use. Or im missunderstanding something here. Or maybe some code that can use to replace this one? Thanks

Comment: That document that you linked to is the MySQL reference manual.

Comment: Oracle corporation owns `MySQL`. And Oracle DBMS has something similar to this, which they have as SQL*Loader, like batch process to load tables. [Please refer here for more details](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch05.htm#1004643)

Comment: ok ill check it out about that SQL*Loader, to be honest i dont know what it is. For your answers looks like i should change the connector? ill try to find information about it and let you know if i can make it work. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the info Maheswaran, ill check it out.

Comment: Im sorry, im new to this site, this is just my first question here, and i dont know how to mark a reply as answered. Maheswaran Ravisankar, i consider your answer was clear and orientative enough so now i know what should i do. Im still having trouble and i have more questions, but this one was solved for me. Thanks.